# Programmatically set FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName

Tags: asp.net, configuration, forms-authentication

is it possible to set the [FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.formscookiename.aspx) in Codebehind(f.e. in Global.asax)? All properties that i have seen that lead to this config-parameter are readonly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264813/how-to-change-formscookiename-at-runtime-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reading the link you provided it seems that you can only set it in the configuration section:

The FormsCookieName property value is set in the configuration file for an ASP.NET application by using the name attribute of the forms configuration element.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="member_login.aspx"
    cookieless="UseCookies"
    name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
</authentication>
```

Also, that property only let's you "get" the name right?

So I'm assuming the answer is No.