# Can I change the FormsAuthentication cookie name in asp.net dynamically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I want to set FormsAuthentication cookie name dynammically, for example a guid. how can i do that. I can already  change it to whatever I want in web.config. I just can't do it in code and dynamically.Please help.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="myName" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/Admin/admin" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true"  timeout="40320"/>
</authentication>
```

The reason that I want to do this is, i have several instances of my application on the same host and i do not want them to overwrite each other's cookies.

Comment: Can't you just use `FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName`?

Comment: Also, why do you need to change it dynamically? If you have several instances of the application, why not just change the value in the web.config of each?

Comment: ok. I know it is  an unlikely  situation. but i want my application to have the ability to do it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in code; the property [FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.formscookiename.aspx) is readonly. I would use the following configuration in `web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms configSource="forms.config" />
</authentication>
```

Then give each instance of the application its own `forms.config`:

```
<forms name="CookieNameForThisInstance" />
```

Comment: thanks. I just wanted to know whether  there is  a way to change this at least once in code for each application.

Answer (score 5):

I have been struggling with Cookies with quite a few days. It has been an awesome learning experience.

**So wanted to share the possible ways I found & discovered:** There are several HACKs to modify Forms Authentication Cookie name:

1. You can automate the modification of cookie name under Authenticaiton secion of Web.Config file in Application_Start event in Global.asax. Thanks to Ron for sharing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5606765/6324452). But I could not guarantee that the user whose identity would be used to run application domain have enough privileges to modify the file on disk or not. Hence I needed an improvised solution, so I devised following.
2. Thanks to ILSpy for letting me see inside the FormsAuthentication class, and many thanks to Reflection to let me modify the private field of a class. I used following code to modify the cookie name on run-time with following small piece of code and this worked like a charm !!!

---

```
    protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This will enforce that FormsAuthentication class is loaded from configuration settings for the application.
        FormsAuthentication.Initialize();

        // The new cookie name whatever you need can go here, I needed some value from my application setting to be prefixed so I used it.
        string newCookieName = string.Format("{0}.ASPXAUTH", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeSettingThatIsUniquetoSite"]);

        // Modifying underlying baking field that points to FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName         
        Type type = typeof(FormsAuthentication);
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo field = type.GetField("_FormsName", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
        field.SetValue(null, newCookieName);
    }
```

---

Suggestions, loopholes are requested as this is my first answer on this forum.